# Приём разорванного TCP пакета: ждать дальше или писать ответ

Tags: tcp-ip, сокет

Реализую на boost::asio сервер. Встала проблема с реализацией протокола. Вот тут и всплыл вопрос о разорванных пакетах. Не понятно, когда ждать следующую порцию данных, а когда ответить. Понятно, что TCP гарантирует доставку данных.

Допустим взять протокол XMPP. Вот как там организовано это? В нём нет никаких упоминаний на длину пакета. И тем не менее длинные пакеты, разорванные пакеты спокойно принимаются и передаются. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Я понимаю, что самое просто решение слать перед своим пакетом данных длину, но хотелось бы обойтись без подобных костылей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Допустим взять протокол XMPP. Вот как
> там организовано это? В нём нет
> никаких упоминаний на длину пакета.

В XMPP и не может быть никакой длины пакета :) Протокол описывает ЧТО передавать и принимать, а КАК - это уже забота самой программы. В этом случе всё относительно просто: поскольку это XML, то в обязательном порядке должен прийти открывающий тег (auth, response, challenge, etc). И данные могут считаться полностью принятыми, если пришёл корректный закрывающий тег.

P.S. А в случае boost::asio смотрите в сторону handle_read.

Comment: Совсем забыл про свой вопрос :) Днём ранее уже сам об этом догадался. Довольно интересный хак со стороны XMPP. Сам планирую юзать JSON, в нём проще - придётся считать кол-во открытых и закрытых скобок.

Comment: Да, парсер JSON-а проще, но только скобками не обойтись, строки тоже надо правильно разбирать. [Смотрите здесь](http://www.json.org/) (и куча готовых парсеров для разных языков)

Comment: Я использую boost::propery_tree в качестве парсера. Я имел в виду количество скобок как показатель конца данных. По аналогии с закрывающим тегом XML.

Comment: Вообще-то подобным методам (используемым "в лоб") сопутствует проблема восстановления протокола при ошибке в формате данных.

Например, посланы данные и парсинг не прошел

    {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method":"add", "params":[1,2,3}, "id":1}

массив params закрывается '}' вместо ']'.

Непонятно, где искать следующий запрос.

Comment: Сейчас поэкспериментировал с jabber.ru. Он меня адекватно посылал всегда, когда нужно. И я кажется понял почему. Если данных принято меньше, чем размер MTU пакета, то можно спокойно разбирать - данных не будет, если же меньше - будем ждать ещё данных.

Comment: Распространенное заблуждение, ведущее к "глюкавым" программам.

Comment: В таком случае объясните, почему даже с ошибками в XML XMPP сервер знает когда нужно ответить, а когда подождать?

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, приведите более подробные примеры диалога с  XMPP сервером (что именно Вас интересует).

Часто обмен XML данными реализуют на базе http транспорта. В http размер передаваемых прикладных данных задается в  заголовке Content-Length http протокола (можно и по другому, используя Transfer-Encoding: chunked, но там тоже задается размер каждого передаваемого куска данных).

--

Только, уверяю Вас, увязки алгоритмов чтения-записи потока байт с размером пакета сетевого уровня (MTU) в подобных программах не делается.

Comment: Плюс мульон. Собственный порт - нафига, если всё решается 80?

Answer (score 2):

[@ReklatsMasters](/users/5227/reklatsmasters), в tcp **нет пакетов**. Конечно, с точки зрения программы (в сети они есть, переменой длины).

Tcp - это просто **поток** байт. Поэтому организация порций данных ложится на прикладной уровень. Можно слать длину порции, можно (как в SMTP) признак конца, можно (как в HTTP) совмещать оба способа.

В любом случае возникают определенные неудобства в программировании (еще не забудьте про таймауты).

Решайте сами в зависимости от Вашей задачи.